# How to find percent increase/decrease with datetime values in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, time-series

I have attached a photo of how the data is formatted when I print the df in Jupyter, please check that for reference.
Set the DATE column as the index, checked the data type of the index, and converted the index to be a datetime index.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv ('UMTMVS.csv',index_col='DATE',parse_dates=True)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

I need to print out percent increase in value from Month/Year to Month/Year and percent decrease in value from Month/Year to Month/Year.

[dataframe format picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRfGN.png)

Comment: Please do not attach photo of data. Copy-paste the text. We cannot grab data from a photo if we want to test a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The first correction pertains to how to read your DataFrame.

Passing *parse_dates* you should define a **list of columns** to be parsed
as dates. So this instruction should be changed to:

```
df = pd.read_csv('UMTMVS.csv', index_col='DATE', parse_dates=['DATE'])
```

and then the second instruction in not needed.

To find the percent change in *UMTMVS* column, use: `df.UMTMVS.pct_change()`.
For your data the result is:

```
DATE
1992-01-01         NaN
1992-02-01    0.110968
1992-03-01    0.073036
1992-04-01   -0.040080
1992-05-01    0.014875
1992-06-01   -0.330455
1992-07-01    0.368293
1992-08-01    0.078386
1992-09-01    0.082884
1992-10-01   -0.030528
1992-11-01   -0.027791
Name: UMTMVS, dtype: float64
```

Maybe you should multiply it by *100*, to get true percents.